# trouble execute a SQL query in oracle10g

Tags: oracle10g

update books set status='reserved' where upper(title) like upper('%Core Servlets and Core Servlets%')

this query is executing when i give '%core%'' or 'core servlets' but not working when it is %Core Servlets and Core Servlets%

is their any restriction on length of like string %Core Servlets and Core Servlets%

Comment: Are u getting any error?

Comment: i am not able to update the database ... it is not giving any error it shows like 0 row(s) updated.

Comment: It's executing either way, it just isn't finding any matching rows to update. So, you have no rows which match that whole string fragment. The two versions that work don't tell you much as they are a different pattern to the one that doesn't find anything. Do you really expect to have a (book? course?) title with the 'core servlets' repeated?

Comment: Core Servlets and Core Servlets is present in my database records under title column... i think this proble is due to the length of the string (Core Servlets and Core Servlets) ...how can i resolve it

Comment: It's not due to the length of the string; not sure why you'd think that. Maybe you have a hard space, or a typo. Maybe you can add the result of `select title from books where upper(title) like '%CORE SERVLETS%'` to the question.

Comment: i am doing a book reservation application ,where i want to change the status of available book to reserved when user clicks the checkbox, their i need to update my database .... so i need to update the status column form available to reserved with respect to tittle checked

Comment: I understand what the update is doing; your data doesn't match what you're trying to update though. Also why would you use 'like' and case-insentivity for this, surely you want to update a specific book (if not a specific copy of a book), not all books with similar titles? I would think you'd use the book's primary key as the checkbox ID and then use that fro the update, not rely on the title.

Comment: thanq for the answer got solved the problem :-)